# How to add a parameter to pass a file to a Jenkins job in a groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I know how to add a "File" parameter (a possibility to pick and upload a file) to a Jenkins job via the Configuration on its web interface. I would like to know how to add the same kind of paremeter file to a job in a groovy script in Scriptive syntax.

```
properties([parameters([
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: ''),
    booleanParam(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: ''),
    *fileParamIWantToAdd*(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: ''),
]), pipelineTriggers([])])
```

Comment: File parameter is not possible for pipeline jobs.